# How to Transform post value from wysihtml5 editor right way to insert into MySql DB

Tags: php, jquery, post, wysihtml5

I have a little Form for adding articles to a blog the form processing is via JQuery

JQUERY CODE

```
 $(function() {$(".submit").click(function() {
var title = $("#title").val();
var article = $("#article").val();
var tags = $("#tags").val();
var category = $("#category").val();
var subcategory = $("#subcategory").val();
var username = $("#username").val();
var views = $("#views").val();
var earning = $("#earning").val();
var dataString = 'title='+ title + '&article='+ article + '&tags='+ tags + '&category=' + category + '&subcategory=' + subcategory + '&username=' + username + '&views=' + views + '&earning=' + earning;

if(title=='' || article=='' || tags=='' || category=='' || subcategory=='' || username=='' || views=='' || earning=='')
{

            $("#message-fail").fadeIn("slow");

setTimeout(function(){
    $("#message-fail").fadeOut("slow");
},5000);
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "inc/add-article.php",
data: dataString,
success: function showSuccessMessage(){
        $("#message-success").fadeIn("slow");
                                    setTimeout(function(){


    $("#message-success").fadeOut("slow");
},5000);   
                                }
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

This is my add-article.php file

```
<?php









if($_POST)

{
$title=$_POST['title'];

$article= $_POST['article'];




$tags=$_POST['tags'];

$category=$_POST['category'];

$subcategory=$_POST['subcategory'];

$username=$_POST['username'];

$views=$_POST['views'];

$earning=$_POST['earning'];


$date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');





$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'bfggyys');

if (!$link) {

    die('Verbindung nicht möglich : ' . mysql_error());

}



// benutze Datenbank foo

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('blog', $link);

if (!$db_selected) {

    die ('Kann foo nicht benutzen : ' . mysql_error());

}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET title='".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."', article='".$article2."', tags='".mysql_real_escape_string($tags)."', category='".mysql_real_escape_string($category)."', subcategory='".mysql_real_escape_string($subcategory)."', username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', views='".mysql_real_escape_string($views)."', earning='".mysql_real_escape_string($earning)."', date='".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."'");

}else { }



?>
```

My Problem is i dont know how to transform the value from article the right way to insert it into db if i insert now a post article value cant be inserted because it stopps inserting into mysql on first space sign  .How can i escape it right for inserting into mysql db?